# What attribute combo qualifies a class as a Data Component for ASP.NET?

Tags: .net, asp.net, objectdatasource

When I use the wizard to configure an ObjectDataSource control, it presents a list of candiate business objects.  This is of course quite long in even a small project, but it can be fileterd to only show Data Components.

How can I decorate my service classes so that only they appear in this list when I filter it to "Show only data components"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to decorate it with the

```
[DataObjectAttribute]
```

and add the following using statement

```
using System.ComponentModel;
```